# How to update the version in a exe.manifest file using powershell?

Tags: xml, powershell

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" standalone="yes"?>
<assembly xmlns="urn:schemas-microsoft-com:asm.v1" manifestVersion="1.0">
<assemblyIdentity
    version="0.0.0.0"
    processorArchitecture="X86"
    name="ABC"
    type="win32"
/>
```

I want to update the version using powershell script.
I tried writing this code

```
$manifest =[xml]( Get-Content $file.fullname)
$manifest.assemblyIdentity.version = "6.2.0.0"
```

It is not working.

Answer (score 2):

```
[xml]$xml = Get-Content $file.fullname
$xml.assembly.assemblyIdentity.version = "6.2.0.0"
$xml.Save($file.fullname)
```

Answer (score -1):

Use this:

```
$xmlPath = "FilePath"
$xml = New-Object XML
$xml.Load($xmlPath)
$Namespace = New-Object -TypeName "Xml.XmlNamespaceManager" -ArgumentList $xml.NameTable
$Namespace.AddNamespace("schemas-microsoft-com", $xml.DocumentElement.NamespaceURI)
$nodes =  $xml.SelectNodes("schemas-microsoft-com:assemblyIdentity")
ForEach ($node in $nodes) {
  $node.SetAttribute("version", "6.2.0.0")
}
$xml.Save($xmlPath)
```

Comment: [xml]$xml = Get-Content $file.fullname
$xml.assembly.assemblyIdentity.version = "6.2.0.0"
$xml.Save($file.fullname)

Comment: Thanks for updating - a step in the right direction, but your code is still broken (btw, you cannot notify me by full name, you need to use `@<userNameOrPrefix>`): The query either needs the full path to the element of interest or prefix `//`, and the `.SelectNodes()` call must be passed `$Namespace` (which is confusingly named, as it is a namespace _manager_) as the 2nd argument.